# What is a good GUI file renamer that takes files from command line URIs?

Tags: nemo, batch-rename

Looking for a GUI mass file renamer that can be run from a selection of files in Nemo. Nemo has a built-in placeholder for a mass rename tool so you can provide the name of the app to run to rename multiple files. The files selected are passed as URIs on the command line.

I have looked at pyrenamer, gprenamer and neither seem to accept a list of files from the command line.

Anyone know of any?

Comment: I have written my own solution for this using a nemo action and a shell script that uses yad, to basically provide a GUI to the shell `rename` command, but with sequential numbering add in. I'll post it somewhere soon!

Comment: krename accepts file names on the command line, but will require a number of libraries (qt ...) which may not be installed by default on your system.

Comment: (Hee hee. There also seems to be a bug in the nemo built-in mass Rename connector in that it generates incorrect URIs for filenames with spaces...)

Answer (score 9):

### Update 02/06/2021:

Linux Mint team developed a new tool named [Bulky](https://github.com/linuxmint/bulky) which will be available in the next release. At the moment, you can install it manually and use it with Nemo. No more need for Thunar.

### Original Answer

I have found the solution from this [link](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=162435).
Thunar file manager has a bulk rename tool. I feel it is simple and easy to use compared to other bulk renamers.

#### Step 1

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends thunar
```

Above command installs core Thunar files.

#### Step 2

Open Nemo `Preferences` dialog from `Edit` menu and navigate to `Behavior` tab. Scroll down to the bottom of the menu and add the following command as the *Command to invoke when renaming multiple items*:

```
thunar --bulk-rename
```

Now select any number of files and press `F2` or right click and select `Rename...`.