# Install Bulky (Nemo bulk renamer)

Tags: 20.04, mint, batch-rename, nemo

I can not figure out how to install the new feature that is coming to Linux Mint 20.2. The bulk renamer Bulky (https://github.com/linuxmint/bulky).

Because it's such a new thing, i can't really find tutorials online... and i do not understand very well the concept of makefiles and stuff like that. Has anyone installed it/tested it? I would like to stop installing Thunar just for the bulk renamer!

This is related, and what got me interested in the first place:
[What is a good GUI file renamer that takes files from command line URIs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468172/what-is-a-good-gui-file-renamer-that-takes-files-from-command-line-uris)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm really sorry, it is exactly 20.04 LTS! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (and newer) the compilation process is straightforward:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dpkg-dev debhelper

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/bulky.git
cd bulky/

dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../bulky*.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: I edited, so that users who blindly copy-paste the commands, and Bulky does not install due to changed version number, won't face an issue. See the recently posted other answer, there the person who posted the answer probably had such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

My answer makes one change - an extra step, to identify the created deb.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git dpkg-dev debhelper

$ cd ~/Downloads
$ git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/bulky.git
$ cd bulky/

$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
```

Next, identify the version  of the built deb, located in ~/Downloads:
$ls ~/Downloads/bulky*deb
Example result:
bulky_2.5_all.deb

Using the identified deb file, execute the command
$ sudo apt-get install ../bulky_2.5_all.deb

Comment: If it's just an addition to the existing answer, [please edit it instead](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1349358/edit) of posting a new one.